# What is the energy of the London dispersion force holding together two atoms of the same element?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I read somewhere that the energy is around $U=-\frac{3\alpha I}{4r^6}$ where $\alpha$ is the polarizability and $I$ is the ionization energy but I'm obtaining way too large energies for a lithium crystal.

The shortest distance between two lithium atoms in the crystal is $304 pm$

The first ionization energy of lithium is $520.2 kJ/mol$

I've found various polarizability constants online in papers but I can't really figure them out or the units they are using.

Also, I suspect that I want the dispersion force between $\ce{Li^+}$ ions and not neutral $\ce{Li}$ atoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polarisability as used here has dimensions of volume. The London formula is $$U \approx -\frac{3}2\frac{I_aI_b}{I_a+I_b}\frac{\alpha _a \alpha _b}{r^6}$$  for two species *a* and *b* so you just need to square $\alpha$.

Comment: So, for a polarizability constant of $24\times 10^{-30}$ which I'm not sure is correct I got a total energy of 290kJ/mol which still seems too high. Is this correct?

Comment: still seems very high

Comment: having looked at some values the polarisability of 24 seems very large, atoms seem to have values not bigger than 10 although I have not done a thorough check on this.

Comment: The source at https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0506106 says about 24 and the source says other sources say 22 and 24. Maybe they mean a different kind of polarizability?

Comment: Volume polarisability is correct. I had a look again and found values for benzene of 25 .10$^{-24}$ ml so that is consistent with your values  in m$^3$. Carbon tetrachloride has a value 10.5 for example. ( I had only looked at nitrogen (1.73) and water (1.44),  before, apologies). An interaction energy of approx 24000 cm$^{-1}$  is still huge, its as large as an electronic excitation, but I can't see what wrong  :(   The ionisation energy and bond length seem ok .

Comment: Thinking again, in the crystal one calculates the Madelung energy $\alpha$ to get at the binding energy $U=-\alpha (1-\rho /R_0)$ where $\rho$ is about 0.1$R_0$ the near neighbour distance and accounts for repulsion. (see the classic C. Kittel  ' Introduction to Solid State Physics') The reason that your previous calculation gives such a large value is the small separation you use.  Normally the centre to centre separation of molecules is not as small  as a bond length.

Comment: The polarizability of ions would be very small right? So in the sea of electron model where we are dealing with $\ce{Li^+}$ the energy would be much smaller right?

Comment: yes; the values I quoted are for molecules, notions, a value similar to He would seem to be reasonable  approx $0.2.10^{-30}$ m$^3$.

Comment: yes; the values I quoted are for molecules, a value similar to He would seem to be reasonable ; value approx $0.2.10^{-30}$ m$^3$ and this would reduce your value very considerably. Atoms and tri-atomics with small atomic number atoms seem to have values in the range 0.2 to 2. H$_2$O = 1.45, H$_2$S = 3.6  as heavy atoms are more polarisable than light ones.